# Rebuilding of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I look for next solution. I have a pandas DataFrame with some columns:

```
A B C D E F
1 . . a . 1
2 . . a . 1
2 . . b . 1
3 . . a . 1
4 . . b . 1
etc
```

In this example only 3 columns are important for me. In the column `D` it is possible to see only 2 letters: `"a"` and `"b"`. Every unique value in the column `A` can have only 3 possibilities: only letter `a` (in the example above value 1), only letter `b` (value 4) or both of them (values 2, saved in two different rows). 
Is it possible to create next DF?

```
A a b
1 1 0
2 1 1
3 1 0
4 0 1
etc
```

The values in the new columns are corresponding values from the column F of original DF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution someself. If somebody wish to know, it could be done with the function `pivot`

```
DF.pivot(index='A', columns='D', values='F')
```